# How do you set a class-level permission using Parse Server?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm migrating an app from Parse.com (hosted) to a self-hosted* Parse Server implementation (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server).

My app relies heavily on Class-Level Permissions so that, for example, global settings can be read by all users with the public key but not edited or deleted without the master key.

On Parse.com these permissions are configurable in the dashboard, but the open source Parse Server doesn't have a dashboard. Maybe there's some way to do this using cloud code?

*I'm using App Engine's managed VM environment although I'm not sure that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the _SCHEMA table in the mongodb datastore and it contains the CLPs I was looking for. Apparently that's where they're stored and they were migrated along with the rest of my data from Parse.com. I've confirmed that updating those values affects data access permissions

Answer (score 3):

Using Rest API:

```json
// POST http://my-parse-server.com/schemas/Announcement
// Set the X-Parse-Application-Id and X-Parse-Master-Key header
// body:
{
  classLevelPermissions:
  {
    "find": {
      "requiresAuthentication": true,
      "role:admin": true
    },
    "get": {
      "requiresAuthentication": true,
      "role:admin": true
    },
    "create": { "role:admin": true },
    "update": { "role:admin": true },
    "delete": { "role:admin": true }
  }
}
```

**Ref:**

- https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#requires-authentication-permission-requires-parse-server---230
- https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#class-level-permissions